# Extending Web API class constructor

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering it it's possible to extend a built in Web API class `Request` for instance to trigger an immediately invoked function upon instantiation of the class constructor.

So that whenever `const myRequest = new Request('http://...', {...});` is declared a trigger will be fired. For instance a `console.log()` or another global function. Without ever explicitly having to call `Request.prototype.trigger` or anything similar.

Any help/suggested learning material appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like a design smell, anyway

Comment: you want to override a so called built-in Class' constructor?

Comment: Well override but preserve the existing functionality, just add an additional function which runs immediately. So in my mind extend the constructor but technically, perhaps. TIL "design smell" :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend it into your own class

```
class MyRequest extends Request{
   constructor(...args){
       super(...args);
       console.log("extended")
   }
}
```

or overwrite the built in Request (bad idea)

```
const originalRequest = Request
Request = function(...args){
    console.log("overwrite");
   return new originalRequest(...args)
}
```

Comment: Nice one! I was over-thinking this one pretty hard. Thanks a lot! :+1:

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a private function and overwritting your Request class - this is not really recommended as if you make *your own* implementation, you should *name* it yourself so you know it's not the default object.

```js
void function(){
  
  const request = window.Request;
  
  class Request extends request {
    
    constructor(){
    
      super( ...arguments );
      
      console.log( 'Calling mock request' );
    
    }
    
  }
  
  window.Request = Request;
  
}();

console.log( new Request( 'http:google.com' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, another perfect answer, just seconds too slow to be the accepted answer. Thanks for taking the time. Have an upvote! :)